# What formula can I use to search a value and add cells two rows over across multiple sheets?

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to add values across sheets and an having a hard time finding a good formula to do this with.

I have over 300 sheets, representing rooms, that have two relevant columns, one that has dates and another with water consumption usage that look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fD9J.png)

Issue is, the dates are inconsistent across all of the sheets. The full range of dates should be from 1/13/2023 to 2/6/2023 but many sheets are missing dates because water consumption wasn't read that date.

I have a summary page with a column representing the full range of dates and another column where I want to add usage for the specific date across all the sheets to show how much water was consumed that day across all rooms. Since the dates and usage are all in different cells, I can't call out specific cells. What is the best formula to use and how can I format it correctly?

I tried SUMIF formula's as well as IF formulas and tried nesting variations of them, but ultimately I am having trouble finding a formula/formatting that allows me to call out a cell value (ex, 2/6/2023) and sum the value two columns over. I am fairly new to the more advanced formula's so please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: it is referred to as a [3D SUMIFS](https://exceljet.net/formulas/sum-across-multiple-worksheets-with-criteria)

Comment: You could avoid INDIRECT in Office 365 something like this: `=SUM((TOCOL(Sheet1:Sheet3!A1:A30)=A2)*(TOCOL(Sheet1:Sheet3!C1:BC30))` where `A2` would be the date to sum.